# I need help using SQL case statements in where clauses

Tags: sql-server

In the below code I have 2 date comparisons in my where clause that I need to change to a CASE statement that allows for a NULL value for the variable.  When the @StartDate variable is null, then all rows should be selected regardless of the StartDate value.  If @StartDate is not null, then all rows with StartDate >= @StartDate should be selected.

The other issue is with the LotCode in the Where clause.  The statement works fine as is, but it does not return NULL values of LotCode when @LotCode is null.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
declare @StartDate datetime
declare @EndDate datetime
declare @ItemNumber varchar(50)
declare @LotCode varchar(50)

set @StartDate = '12-25-2016'
set @Enddate = '03-08-2017'
set @ItemNumber = NULL
set @LotCode = NULL


SELECT h.[CreateTime] 
      ,h.[SubmitTime]
      ,h.[CreateUserName]
      ,h.[TransactionCode]
      ,h.[TransferOrderCode]
      ,u.[ItemCode]
      ,u.[LotCode]
      ,u.[FromSiteCode]
      ,u.[ToSiteCode]
      ,u.[ToBinCode]
      ,u.[TransferQuantity]


  FROM GP7_TrxSiteTransfer h
  left join GP7_TrxSiteTransferUnit u
       on h.oid = u.TrxSiteTransferOid

where transactionstatus = '4'

and h.createtime >= @StartDate
-- I would like to replace the above statement with a comparison that allows for the variable to be null and select all values of EndDate.... tried the below line but it doesn't work
--and h.createtime >= (Case @StartDate when null then @StartDate else h.createtime end)  

and h.createtime <= @EndDate
-- I would like to replace the above statement with a comparison that allows for the variable to be null and select all values of EndDate.... tried the below line but it doesn't work
--and h.createtime <= (Case @EndDate when null then @EndDate else h.createtime end) 

and u.ItemCode = (Case @ItemNumber when null then @ItemNumber else ItemCode End)

and u.LotCode = (Case @LotCode when null then @LotCode else LotCode End)     -- I need to change this statement to select all values of LotCode including NULL.  Right now it includes all non-null values

order by h.createtime
```

Comment: If your sql query is dynamic then you might want to use the [stored procedure/sql command](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [COALESCE function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) instead of `CASE` like this:

```
and coalesce(h.createtime, @StartDate) >= @StartDate
and coalesce(h.createtime, @EndDate) <= @EndDate
```

If you still want to use the case you just have to fix it:

```
 ... >= (Case when @StartDate is null then h.createtime else @StartDate end)
```

The same for `@EndDate`

Answer (score 0):

All of your `case` statements are the reverse of what you want.
Instead of

```
Case @<var> when null then @<var> else <col> End
```

use

```
Case @<var> when null then <col> else @<var> End
```

e.g.

```
Case @LotCode when null then LotCode else @LotCode End
```

This will compare against the variable when it is not NULL, or against the column when the variable is NULL.  This is the same as using `coalesce(@LotCode, LotCode)`.

Changing the date comparisons in the same way will correct them too.

Answer (score 0):

```
This worked:

where transactionstatus = '4'

and (h.createtime >= @StartDate OR @StartDate IS NULL)
and (h.createtime <= @EndDate OR @EndDate IS NULL)
and (u.ItemCode = @ItemNumber or @ItemNumber IS NULL)
and (u.LotCode = @LotCode or @LotCode IS NULL)
```